# PhoneGap 2.2.0 navigation.globalization.getLocaleName and jQuery i18n plugin causes app to stall on iOS at spinner

Tags: cordova, jquery-plugins, localization

I'm using the new built-in globalization support in PhoneGap 2.2.0 using navigator.globalization.getLocaleName to figure out what the device locale is. However, the app just stalls and the spinner (enhanced by jQuery Mobile) just spins indefinitely.  I have tested both on iOS and Android with the same result. Here's my code:

```
$('#home').live('pageinit', function()
{
var app_language = localValue('app_language');

//console.log('app_language variable holds: '+app_language);
if ( app_language === '' )
{
    var successCB = function(locale)
    {
        alert('success');
        //console.log('locale is: '+locale.value);
        window.localStorage.setItem('app_language', locale.value);
    };

    var failureCB = function(error)
    {
        if (error = Globalization.UNKNOWN_ERROR)
        {
            console.log('error getting locale');
        }
    };

    navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(successCB, failureCB);

}
else
{
    console.log('got this far');
    switch (app_language)
    {
    case 'en_CA':
        //console.log('using English dictionary');
        $.i18n.setDictionary(lang_english);
        break;
    case 'en_US':
        //console.log('using English dictionary');
        $.i18n.setDictionary(lang_english);
        break;
    case 'fr_CA':
        //console.log('using Canadian French dictionary');
        $.i18n.setDictionary(lang_french);
        break;
    default:
        //console.log('default to English dictionary');
        $.i18n.setDictionary(lang_english);
    }
}

$('#hit_to_begin').text($.i18n._('helper_text'));

});
```

If I comment out the call to navigator.globalization.getLocaleName it works fine. The behavior is the same on both iOS and Android 4.0+. I am really at an end here.

Comment: Are you waiting for the "deviceready" event?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you fixed the issue?